# What is the most efficient way to pass data (list of pairs of [Integer + Double]) between two Google App Engine instances?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, serialization

What is the most efficient way to pass data (list of pairs of [Integer, Double]) between two Google App Engine instances ?

Currently I use Java binary serialization. Frontend servlet receives data from the client in JSON format. I convert it to `byte[]` using `ObjectOutput.writeObject` and then send it to backend servlet via HTTP POST. It's not in production yet.

Should I just pass client's JSON as it is to backend? It seems more logical. But it's bigger in size.

Or should I use Google Protocol Buffers as stated in **[this benchmark article](http://www.eishay.com/2009/03/more-on-benchmarking-java-serialization.html)** ?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to try out the 3 options for yourself.  For a data structure this simple, the effort needed to try the alternatives should be relatively small.  (The chances of someone here having tried these 3 alternatives on your specific use-case is pretty small, so any direct answers are likely to be mostly best-guesses.)

But before you spend time on this, ask yourself if you can justify it.  Is there a real performance problem here, or is it just conjecture that there is likely to be a problem?  Can you quantify it?  Is it worth expending effort on it?

---

And if we are making guesses, I'd think that you'll get best performance by using a simple `DataOutputStream` / `DataInputStream` pair.  Write alternating `int` and `double` values extracted from the input list, and at the other end read the values and reconstruct the equivalent list of pairs at the other end.  (And start by sending the list length to make the reconstruction more efficient.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give this question couple more hours and then will mark an answer.